# Function to restore a database - [PostgreSQL]

Tags: postgresql, restore

I want to know if there is a way to restore a *Postgres* database with command in a function.

Something like:

```
create or replace function restore_database(database_name varchar(255)) returns void as $$
    BEGIN 
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'pg_restore -p 5432 -h localhost -d database_name -U postgres -v "C:\temp\archive.backup"'
    END; $$
language 'plpgsql';
```

Its only an example above, I know it wont work and its prompt commands lines. But I want to know if there is any type of commands that could make this kind of restore.

for example, in Oracle and SQL Server I can make something like that:

**Oracle:**

```
h1 := DBMS_DATAPUMP.open(operation => 'IMPORT', job_mode => 'SCHEMA', job_name => v_job_name);
DBMS_DATAPUMP.add_file(h1, backup_file, 'LOCALBKP');
DBMS_DATAPUMP.metadata_remap....
DBMS_DATAPUMP.start_job (h1);
```

**SQL Server**

```
RESTORE DATABASE database_name FROM DISK = ''C:\temp\file.bak'';
```

This two statements will work in Oracle  and SQL Server.

Comment: There is no SQL statement in Postgres to restore a dump

Comment: Thanks for your answer!